# Error Writing a Copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a copy constructor for a class but I get these two error messages, which I cannot decipher. Can somebody please tell me what I am doing incorrect?

```
class Critter
    {

    public:
        Critter(){}
        explicit Critter(int hungerLevelParam):hungerLevel(hungerLevelParam){}
        int GetHungerLevel(){return hungerLevel;}

        // Copy Constructors
        explicit Critter(const Critter& rhs);
        const Critter& operator=(const Critter& rhs);

    private:
        int hungerLevel;
    };

Critter::Critter(const Critter& rhs)
    {
    *this = rhs;
    }

const Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& rhs)
    {
    if(this != &rhs)
        {
        this->hungerLevel = rhs.GetHungerLevel(); // ERROR: object has type qualifier not compatible with member function
        }
    return *this;
    }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    Critter aCritter2(10);
    Critter aCritter3 = aCritter2; // ERROR : No suitable copy constructor
    Critter aCritter4(aCritter3);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Don't make the copy ctor explicit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `int GetHungerLevel() const {return hungerLevel;}`

Otherwise, you aren't allowed to call `GetHungerLevel()` using the reference-to-const `rhs`.

Also, you can't do copy-initialization with an `explicit` copy constructor, only direct initialization: `Critter aCritter3(aCritter2);`

Probably you want to make the copy ctor non-explicit rather than necessarily change the definition of `aCritter3`, but your call.

Comment: I dont think i understand. Why can't I call a getter even if it is a const?

Comment: @kunj2aan: the compiler doesn't know that `GetHungerLevel()` is a getter. I suppose in this example it could work it out, but the language standard forbids it from doing so. The purpose of using a reference-to-`const`, is to stop yourself from calling non-const member functions (and doing other non-const things, like assigning to data members). So, if you want to call a function via reference-to-const, you mark the function `const`. That's how const-correctness works in C++.

Comment: Is there a place where I can learn about the effective usage of const? This thing is driving me nuts. Thanks. –

Comment: @kunj2aan a good rule of thumb is to mark all methods that logically aren't supposed to change your object as `const`.

Answer (score 4):

1) You declared your copy constructor `explicit` (do you need it to be explicit?), so the correct syntax is

```
Critter aCritter3 (aCritter2);
```

not

```
Critter aCritter3 = aCritter2;
```

2) Also, the proper signature for an assignment operator is:

```
Critter& operator=(const Critter& rhs);
```

3) The method `GetHungerLevel` should be `const`, but you don't *need* to use it - you can just write:

```
this->hungerLevel = rhs.hungerLevel;
```

Comment: That's not the proper signature of an assignment operator.  It can't be a const function.  Well, it could, I guess, but it'd be pretty useless.

Comment: Since an assignment would be changing the object, wouldn't declaring it const be incorrect?

Comment: Your *proper* signature for assignment is incorrect. Assignment is clearly a non-const operation!

Comment: @kunj2aan yes, but usually you don't return a `const` from `operator =`.

Answer (score 2):

add const qualifier to  GetHungerLevel()

```
  int GetHungerLevel() const {return hungerLevel;}
```